RealSense D435 No Frames Received









librealsense
2.55.1 RELEASE


OS
Linux


Name
Intel RealSense D435


Serial Number
018322071320


Firmware Version
5.16.0.1


Advanced Mode
YES


Camera Locked
YES


Usb Type Descriptor
2.1


Product Line
D400


Asic Serial Number
020223021172


Firmware Update Id
020223021172


Dfu Device Path




No frames received! I've tried many options and settings, but the Intel RealSense Viewer v2.55.1 reports No Frames Received!  repeatedly. Please advise.  I purchased this device on Amazon recently and tested it for about five minutes, then set it aside for a few weeks. When I plugged it back in to start working with it, the viewer performed a firmware update, and hasn't worked since. Any ideas on things I should try?
